# JavaScript XHR w/ GitHub API

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy, github-api

I'm trying to use XHR to access the GitHub HTTP API, and I'm being rather badly defeated by the Same Origin Policy.  I'm quite sure that easyXDM is overkill for this, but I don't know what else (if there is anything else) that I can use.  Is there some easier way than easyXDM to get from my website to the GitHub API?

Comment: Have you looked at Yahoo Pipes? I honestly haven't really, but seems like it might help

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory: no dice.  Pipes is designed for parsing/transforming RSS/Atom, not JSON.  Good thought though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out GitHub API supports JSON-P.  from http://developer.github.com/v3/#json-p-callbacks:

> You can send a `callback` parameter to any GET call to have the
>   results wrapped in a JSON function. This is typically used when
>   browsers want to embed GitHub content in web pages by **getting around
>   cross domain issues**.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 2):

This is your friend:

http://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing

Comment: from the second text paragraph: "Any domain that is registered as an OAuth Application is accepted."  OAuth needs a client ID, and I don't want to put a client ID in (quasi-)publicly-available JavaScript.  At the same time, though, the GitHub people say they're "looking into adding CORS support" but "need to review some of the security implications" (emailed to me recently).  And it's hard to do OAuth on a static (jekyll-generated) site.